# View function is not working properly after including bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing an HTML page that takes input from user via html form and "POST" method and submits it to a link. the link is attatched to a view which accesses a data base entry based on the info passed by the user. But, when i include bootstrap code for navbar header in that HTML page it is not able to access the database.

my view function is

```
def favorite(request,album_id):

    album = get_object_or_404(Album,id = album_id)

    try:

       selected_song = album.song_set.get(id = request.POST['song'])
    except:

       return render(request,'music/detail.html', {'album':album,'error_message':'No song selected!!'})

   else:

       selected_song.isFavorite = True

       selected_song.save()

       return render(request,'music/detail.html',{'album':album})
```

the HTML page is -

```
{% extends 'music/base.html' %}
{% block body %}

{% if error_message %}

<p><strong>{{error_message}}</strong></p>

{% endif %}

<img src = "{{album.album_logo}}">

<h1>The album is {{album}} </h1>

<h2>Artist - {{album.artist}}</h2>

<h3>The songs in this album are: </h3>

<form action = "{%url 'music:favorite' album.id %}" method = "post">

 {% csrf_token %}

 {% for song in album.song_set.all %}

 <input type = "radio" id = "song{{forloop.counter}}" name = "song" value = "{{song.id}}">

 <label for = "song{{forloop.counter}}">

     {{song.song_title}}

     {% if song.isFavorite == True %}

     ' fav '

     {% endif %}
     </label><br>

{% endfor %}

<input type = 'submit' value = "Favorite">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

while the base template code is 'music/base.html' -

```
<html>

<head>{% load staticfiles %}

<title>

{% block title %}

{% endblock %}

</title>

<link rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = "{% static 
'music/style.css' %}">

<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
>

<script

src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"

integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="

crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

<nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse">

<div class = "container-fluid">

 <div class = "navbar - header">

<a class = "navbar-brand" href = "{%url 'music:index' %}">Vibe</a>

<button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#topNavBar">

<span class = "icon-bar"></span>

<span class = "icon-bar"></span>

<span class = "icon-bar"></span>

</button>

</div>

<div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "topNavBar">

<ul class = "nav navbar-nav">

<li class = "">

<a href = "{% url 'music:index' %}">

<span class = "glyphicon-cd" aria-hidden = "true"></span>&nbsp;Albums

</a></li>

<li class = "">

<a href = "{% url 'music:index' %}">

<span class = "glyphicon-cd" aria-hidden = "true"></span>&nbsp;Songs

</a>

</li>

<form class = "navbar-form navbar-left" role = "search" method = "get" 
action 
= "#">

<div class = "form-group">

<input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "q" value = "">

</div>

<button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default">Search</button>

<ul class = 'navbar-nav navbar-right'>

<li class = "">

<a href = "#">

<span class = "glyphicon-power" aria-hidden = "true"></span>&nbsp;Add 
 Album</span>

</a>

</li>

<li class = "">

<a href = "#">

<span class = "glyphicon-power" aria-hidden = "true"></span>&nbsp; 
   Logout</span>

</a>

</li>

</div>

</div>

</nav>

{% block body %} 

{% endblock %}

</body>

</html>
```

I am getting the error message corresponding to except block in favorite function( at the top ) , but when i remove bootstrap from code i am getting no such errors.
P.S. the error message is

```
try:

       selected_song = album.song_set.get(id = 
     request.POST['song'])
except:

       return render(request,'music/detail.html', 
    {'album':album,'error_message':'No song selected!!'}
```

## this one which i am passing in the context

Comment: In `music/base.html` you should have `{% load staticfiles %}` on top of your file. But maybe that's been a copy/paste error?

Comment: You're making us guess what the error is.  Please edit the question to include the full error message.

Comment: @J.Ghyllebert i have included `{% load staticfiles %}` on the top of the file but still not able to access the database also when i submit the query to the database i am getting **csrf** token .

Comment: <form class = "navbar-form navbar-left" ... might be missing the csrf token?

Comment: @Matt thanks! the error was i forgot to close the <form> in the base template and it was overriding the form action in my html page.

Comment: @shaileshbhagat So everything is working now?

Comment: Yeah, it is thanks !